# How to get only the unique values from list C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

For example, I have a list of excel cells

```
List<Cell> cells = new List<Cell>
{
   new Cell("4"),
   new Cell("Hez"),
   new Cell("Method"),
   new Cell("4"),
   new Cell("Val"),
   new Cell("Method"),
}
```

I need to get the only unique cell (in this case Cell("Val"), Cell("Hez")) so Distinct() is not for me.

I found this solution but it doesn't return any data at all

```
var uniqueTest = allData.GroupBy(cell => cell)
                        .Where(group => group.ToString().Count() == 1)
                        .Select(group => group.Key);
```

I think the problem is Cell object doesn't contain any comparison methods (This is IronXl lib) so this is why I'm using ToString() here.

But I don't quite understand LINQ yet, so any explanation or advice is appreciated.

Remarks:

I need to get a list of cells back, but with unique values.

Comment: `group.Count() == 1` and yes, you would need to implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. Another alternative is to use a `HashSet` with a custom comparer, loop the list and check the hashset as you go along

Comment: Why is `Hez` not also a unique cell?

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski fixed it, but this is not the point

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it is :) my mistake

Comment: If `Cell` has only value, why don't use `GroupBy(cell => cell.Value)`? `GroupBy` also can accept a custom `IEqualityComparer`

Comment: Your `ToString()` is in the wrong place. Calling `ToString()` on a Grouping doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski thanks for the answer. This will return a list of values, but I need to get a list of cells

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: Group the cells by their value.
Step 2: Keep only the groups of size 1.
Step 3: Get the only item from each group.

```
var uniqueCells =
    allData.GroupBy(cell => cell.Value) //Step 1
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1) //Step 2
    .Select(g => g.Single()) //Step 3
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution, use this if it is enough for you!
But if you _often_ have to group or compare `Cell` objects, you could implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<Cell>`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60714143

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy.

Lets count the value of Number 4 is Key.. then your linq should look like this

```
var uniqueTest = allData.GroupBy(x=> x.Key).Select(x=> x.First()).Select(x=> x.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, and i'm not sure if I do, you can use `.First()` or the more robust `.Single()`

```cs
var uniqueTest = allData.First(c => c.ToString() == "Val");
```

In this sample i'm assuming `c.ToString()` will give you the cell's value. Otherwise it will likely be something like `c.Value` or something.

There are als the `OrDefault` variants.
Check out this article for the differences;
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-in-linq-query1

Answer (score 0):

if you class Cell is something like this.

```
    public class Cell
    {
        public Cell(string mystring)
        {
            MyString = mystring;
        }
        public string MyString { get; set; }
```

then this will work to get a unique list:

```
        List<Cell> UniqueCells = new List<Cell>();

        foreach (var cell in cells)
        {
            if(!UniqueCells.Any(c=>c.MyString == cell.MyString))
            {
                UniqueCells.Add(cell);
            }
        }
```

In this case only the first cell containing 'Method' and '4' will be added. the '!' and '.Any' are the essential parts.